# Vue Material change drawer background

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-material

I have created a vuejs app and i'm using googles material design

I'm trying to find a way to change the background color.

```
<template>
    <div class="page-container">
        <md-app>
            <md-app-toolbar class="md-primary" md-elevation="0">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" @click="toggleMenu" v-if="!menuVisible">
                    <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <span class="md-title">My Title</span>
            </md-app-toolbar>

            <md-app-drawer :md-active.sync="menuVisible" md-persistent="mini">
                <md-toolbar class="md-transparent" md-elevation="0">
                    <span>Navigation</span>

                    <div class="md-toolbar-section-end">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-dense" @click="toggleMenu">
                            <md-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </div>
                </md-toolbar>
                <md-list>
                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon>move_to_inbox</md-icon>
                        <span class="md-list-item-text">Inbox</span>
                    </md-list-item>

                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon>send</md-icon>
                        <span class="md-list-item-text">Sent Mail</span>
                    </md-list-item>

                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
                        <span class="md-list-item-text">Trash</span>
                    </md-list-item>

                    <md-list-item>
                        <md-icon>error</md-icon>
                        <span class="md-list-item-text">Spam</span>
                    </md-list-item>
                </md-list>
            </md-app-drawer>
            <md-app-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quibusdam, non molestias et! Earum magnam, similique, quo recusandae placeat dicta asperiores modi sint ea.
            </md-app-content>
        </md-app>
    </div>
</template>
```

I read if you add the following

```
@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/engine"; // Import the theme engine

@include md-register-theme("default", (
    primary: #3fffbe, // The primary color of your brand
    accent: #1a11e8 // The secondary color of your brand
));

@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/all"; // Apply the theme
```

but not sure how to add it to the drawer to change the backgorund. Any ideas?

Comment: can you specify which version you use ?

Answer (score 1):

try this i think it's working for you

```
@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/engine"; // Import the theme engine

@include md-register-theme("default", (
  primary: md-get-palette-color(blue, A200), // The primary color of your application
  accent: md-get-palette-color(red, A200) // The accent or secondary color
));

@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/all"; // Apply the theme
```

where A200 is The shades are based on color weight, 
that can be 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, A100, A200, A400 or A700

Answer (score 0):

From Vue Material [docs](https://vuematerial.io/themes/concepts):

> Vue Material use classes to apply those color intentions: `md-primary`, `md-accent`, and `md-transparent`. The background color is applied automatically by the theme engine.

This applies to the `md-app-drawer` component as well. What you can do is to override its default class styles. I guess it happens to be under `md-drawer` class, so it goes as:

```
.md-drawer {
    background: blue !important; // makes the drawer partially blue
}
```

`md-drawer` has a set of child components (like `md-list`) styles of which you would also have to override. Was your actual question "Is there a way to make it with theme setup?". If so, I think the answer would be no.